# CSS - On Hover, Show 'Niece'

Tags: css, css-selectors

Here's the code I have:

```
<div class="hoverDiv">Hover</div>
<div>
    <div class="hoverDivShow"></div>
</div>



.hoverDivShow {
    display: none;
}
.hoverDiv:hover ~ .hoverDivShow {
    display: block;
}
```

What I've been trying to do, is make hoverDivShow appear when hoverDiv is hovered over.

The HTML won't be able to change.

I've looked elsewhere, and have been unable to find any solutions. Not really sure what I'm doing right/wrong. Help would be nice.

Thanks!

Comment: is `.hoverDivShow` supposed to be inside that second div?

Comment: Yes, it's supposed to be there. My bad. It's like that in my actual code.

Comment: It works for me... Are you trying to add text to the `.hoverDivShow`?

Answer (score 6):

You need to use `.hoverDiv:hover ~ div .hoverDivShow` as the "niece" selector. The idea is to select a `<div>` that is the sibling of `.hoverDiv`, then select a child of that sibling that has the class `hoverDivShow`.

Here's a working demo:

```css
.hoverDivShow {
    display: none;
}
.hoverDiv:hover ~ div .hoverDivShow {
    display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="hoverDiv">Hover</div>
<div>
    <div class="hoverDivShow">I'm hidden until you hover!</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you, this was exactly what I was looking for!

Answer (score 2):

Your second css rule `.hoverDiv:hover ~ .hoverDivShow { display: block }` uses a **general sibling selector**. You are searching for **all** elements that follow `.hoverDiv` on the **same DOM level** with a class of `hoverDivShow`. If you review your structure you will notice that such elements don't exist.

[As pointed out by Ed Cottrell](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33700126/1147595), there does exist a sibling with a child that has that class though. So using the general sibling selector you need to target the child of that sibling `.hoverDiv:hover ~ div .hoverDivShow { [...] }`

[I made a fiddle for you](https://jsfiddle.net/Deridjian/Lqeqesw4/6/) explaining very visually the targeting structure of the general sibling selector.

In your case you could also use an adjacent sibling selector like this:

```
.hoverDiv:hover + div .hoverDivShow { [...] }
```

The difference is that it will only target the first element directly following your first selector on the same DOM level if it matches your second selector. Check out my fiddle and [this explanation](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_combinators.asp) on w3schools.